# Deserialization does not transfer my bool

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, binaryformatter

I am trying to learn about sockets in C# and decided to create a multiplayer game for practice. While I have gotten quite far in the socket sending, I'm having a strange problem with a boolean always turning true after receiving and deserializing my class from the other client.

The problem arises here:

```cs
void OnDataReceived(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
{
    Connection con = (Connection)e.SyncResult.AsyncState;
    Game.ScoreBoard[currentPlayer] = Serializer.ToScoreCard(con.buffer); //Here
    ...
}
```

*Game.ScoreBoard[currentPlayer].Local* always becomes true, and I'm not sure at all what the problem is. The other values seem to work fine. Connection is a class containing IP, sockets and manages connections and so on. Buffer size is currently 30 000, as I tried enlarging it to make sure that wasn't the problem.

Here's relevant info from the class:

```cs
public ScoreCard(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
    played = (bool[])info.GetValue("Played", typeof(bool[]));
    scores = (int[])info.GetValue("Scores", typeof(int[]));
    bonusScore = (int)info.GetValue("bonusScore", typeof(int));
    local = (bool)info.GetValue("Local", typeof(bool));
}
```

And

```cs
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("Scores", scores, typeof(int[]));
    info.AddValue("Played", played, typeof(bool[]));
    info.AddValue("Name", name, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("bonusScore", bonusScore, typeof(int));
    info.AddValue("Local", local, typeof(bool));
}
```

And here is the serializer class:

```cs
static class Serializer
{
    public static byte[] ToArray(object data)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        b.Serialize(stream, data);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    public static ScoreCard ToScoreCard(byte[] data)
    {
        ScoreCard sc;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        sc = (ScoreCard)b.Deserialize(stream);
        return sc;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do, or even if the information provided is enough for you to be able to solve my problem. If necessary, I could provide more information. I just find it strange that seemingly only that boolean is unable to work correctly.

**Edit: I found the problem and, *as usual*, it was a simple stupid mistake. oh well, I learnt to make my own binaryformatters at least. Thanks guys :)**

Comment: How are you setting `local` and how are you verifying that it has the expected value just before it is serialized?

Comment: Note:  Binary serialization has terrible performance.  You can easily get two orders of magnitude performance improvement by reading and writing your own byte stream directly.  For a game, this will be a big deal.  Try creating a structure instead.

Comment: @Ted a "struct" will make almost zero difference here, and could be worse due to boxing. That is unrelated and misleading.

Comment: The bool shouldn't switch - you're not imagining it. The questions then become, a:  are you sure it wasn't true before, and b: was the data sent intact. Unrelated, but that data would be much smaller with protobuf-net... pretty much a perfect fit. Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: Or maybe getting set to true afterwards for some reason in the parts of your source code not displayed.

Comment: I did jump to the struct idea a bit early.  Structs can have massive performance benefits in certain cases - especially when lots of objects are being allocated and deallocated regularly.  I think I agree with you that they may not be applicable to this case.

Comment: Can we see .Local ? Or better: the entire class? I wonder if the problem here is in the code we can't see

Comment: Use ProtocolBuffers for a production game...

Answer (score 1):

The performance of BinaryFormatter is terrible.  Every object it serializes has a ton of overhead, and in my experience a formatter that takes > 40 seconds to serialize an object in binary can be done in < 1 second by a custom binary writer.

You might want to consider this:

```
static class Serializer
{
    public static byte[] MakePacket(ScoreCard data)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
            sw.Write(1); // This indicates "version one" of your data format - you can modify the code to support multiple versions by using this
            sw.Write(data.Name);
            sw.Write(data.scores.Length);
            foreach (int score in data.scores) {
                sw.Write(score);
            }
            sw.Write(data.played.Length);
            foreach (bool played in data.played) {
                sw.Write(played );
            }
            sw.Write(data.bonusScore);
            sw.Write(data.local);
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    public static ScoreCard ReadPacket(byte[] data)
    {
        ScoreCard sc = new ScoreCard();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            int ver = sr.ReadInt32();
            switch (ver) {
                case 1:
                    sc.name = sr.ReadString();
                    sc.scores = new int[sr.ReadInt32()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < sc.scores.Length; i++) {
                        sc.scores[i] = sr.ReadInt32();
                    }
                    sc.played = new bool[sr.ReadInt32()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < sc.scores.Length; i++) {
                        sc.played [i] = sr.ReadBool();
                    }
                    sc.BonusScore = sr.ReadInt32();
                    sc.Local = sr.ReadBool();
                    break;
                default: 
                    throw new Exception("Unrecognized network protocol");
            }
        }
        return sc;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is at best tangential to the original question. Besides, there are libraries for this sort of thing :) for the record,  don't disagree: BF has many failings... Just... This doesn't really address the question, IMO

Comment: Correct, it's very tangential, however it's also much easier to debug and see whether correct values are being serialized/deserialized.  Whereas BinaryFormatter is a big black box, this code can be stepped through.  As a side question, what good libraries do you like to use for this kind of thing?

Comment: I'm somewhat biased, but I like protobuf-net; trivial to setup, and very efficient both on the wire and CPU-wise

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this version right now. As a side question, if I want to send different types of data, should I use different sockets? I guess with your version, it would be as easy as changing the "version" though. Seems simple. I just don't know if having multiple (maybe a lot) of sockets to the same IP is plausible.

Comment: @user1547040, I would suggest having two indicators: one int would be "type of packet", and the second int would be "version of packet schema".  You can certainly have lots of sockets, but you can run into potential trouble if one socket gets delayed and the other moves forward at full speed.

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks for the recommendation - will look at protobuf.